# Is it possible to delete a Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics

I have several redundant Google Analytics accounts for the same site and I wish to remove a few as their data is invalid.

How does one go about removing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the Google help page [Delete/Cancel Analytics Accounts](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1009696&topic=1009690&ctx=topic):

> ```
> 1. Remove the Analytics javascript code snippet from all your pages.
> 2. Click the Admin tab at the top right of any Analytics page.
> 3. Click the account that you want to delete.
> 4. Click the Account Settings tab.
> 5. Click the Delete this account link.
> ```